# "identifier not found" error in Windows but not in Mac

Tags: c++, qt

I have this function that works fine in my mac when when I try to compile my program in Windows I get an error:

```
std::string myMainWindow::getPlansPath() {
    char cwd[1024];
    if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL) {
        printf("Current working dir: %s\n", cwd);
    } else {
        perror("getcwd() error");
    }

    std::string path = std::string(cwd) + std::string("/myfolder");

    return path;
}
```

Error:

```
C:\path\to\project\gui\myMainWindow.cxx(876): error C3861: 'getcwd': identifier not found
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

What can it be?

UPDATE:

I end up using `QDir::currentPath()` which was exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Since this is tagged for the `Qt` framework: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#current](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#current)

Comment: A `c++17` option is: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path)

Answer (score 1):

[`getcwd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html) is an UNIX specific function, it does not exist in Windows, the fact that it belongs to the `<unistd.h>` library is a good hint to that. A possible solution would be to use [`_getcwd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getcwd-wgetcwd?view=vs-2019) though I'm not familiar with it's use, I gather by the MSDN page, it's more or less the same.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use `_getcwd` or `_wgetcwd` in the `<direct.h>` or `<wchar.h>` headers on `Windows`.